# Is this superscript notation correct?

Tags: notation

Reading the ["Universal Force Field" paper (pdf)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00051a040) from Rappe et al., 1992, I found equation (13) to be a little strange:

$$
\mathrm{K}_{IJK} = \left( \frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial \theta^2} \right) = \beta \frac{Z_I^* {{_{ZK}}}^{*}}{r_{IK}^5} r_{IJ} r_{JK} \left[ ^3r_{IJ} r_{JK}\left( 1 - \cos^2\theta_0\right) - r_{IK}^2 \cos\theta_0 \right]
$$

For clarity, here is a screenshot from the paper:
[image]

I'm trying to interpret 2 things:

1. The ${_{ZK}}^{*}$, I think, should be $Z_K^*$ , perhaps it was just typewritten small to fit?
2. The $[^3 r_{IJ} ...]$ term. Should it simply be $[3r_{IJ}...]$ or does this mean something else by convention?

Comment: I think it is $Z_{I^*ZK^*}$

Comment: You mean $Z_I ^*  Z_K^*$ ..?. The $[^3$ is what is really tripping me up..

Comment: no, that isn't what it looks like.  I don't have access to the paper, so I can only go by the screenshot.